# Is an AND gate which is noisy 1/3 of the time on only one of its inputs universal?

Tags: logic, circuits, error-correcting-codes, fuzzy-logic

Imagine you have a noise-free NOT gate, and an AND gate with the usual truth table

```
00 0
01 0
10 0    (*)
11 1
```

but such that the case (*) is **wrong 1/3 of the time**, i.e. it gives 1 with probability 1/3, and 0 with probability 2/3.

Is this gate family universal, in the sense that one can write a logic formula with these gates only, and that the probability of obtaining the right outcome is >1/2? (You also have noise-free SWAP and FANOUT, in case that helps).

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an exercise?

Comment: No. My background isn't in the field, but this is a question that came up in a research topic I'm working on. If it is this simple, I'd also be super happy for a "look at the standard textbook XY" of course! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\land_p$ be a gate with error $p$ only when the inputs are $1$ and $0$. What can we say about
$$
(x \land_p y) \land_p (x \land_p y)?
$$
If $x=y=1$ then we always get $1$. If $x = 0$ then we always get $0$. When $x = 1$ and $y = 0$, we get the wrong answer $1$ with probability
$$
p \cdot p + p \cdot (1-p) \cdot p = p^2(2-p).
$$
Call that function $f(p)$. We conclude that this construction results in an $\land_{f(p)}$ gate.

The function $f(p)$ is monotone increasing over $[0,1]$, and satisfies $f(p) \leq 2p^2 = (2p)^2/2$. Therefore $f(f(p)) = (2f(p))^2/2 = (2p)^4/2$. More generally, $f^{(t)}(p) = (2p)^{2^t}/2$.
Consequently, if we apply this construction recursively $O(\log\log(1/\epsilon))$ times to your $\land_{1/3}$ gate, we get an $\land_q$ gate with error $q \leq \epsilon$. This requires a gadget of size $2^{O(\log\log(1/\epsilon))} = \operatorname{polylog}(1/\epsilon)$.

To handle a circuit of size $S$, you need to choose $\epsilon = 1/(2S)$, which results in a blowup of $\operatorname{polylog}(S)$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's a super clear answer, no wonder why you were asking whether this was an exercise! :)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think $polylog(S)$ is an outer bound and I have some thoughts on this. Perhaps I can email you if I get more insights. This answer is a good lead to me.